# What is the proper way to handle a single user action that triggers two indexedDB write events to the same object store?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm working with a web page that has a tabbed display that simply hides all but the selected tab using the `display` style property.  When a new tab is selected, a function is called that gathers some data from the page and writes it to an indexedDB object store to be used to restore the previous state of the tab, such as the selected element and cursor position, none of which seems efficient to save at every individual change.

At the same time, the important data is saved right away, such as a `change` event on a textarea, which will write data to the same object store as above.

My question is what should take place when the user writes new text to one of the textarea elements and, while the textarea still has the focus, clicks a button to navigate away from the tab (not the browser tab but just the tabbed display within  the web page)?  This single user action triggers two database write transactions at the "same" time and on the same object store.

In testing, I have tried to place a large amount of data in the textarea, before navigating away from that tab, in attempt at causing the `change` write event to take more time to complete; but, the write transaction triggered by the `change` event always completes before the event capturing the last state of the tab.

A reason for this may be that, apart from the last scroll position, all the data is taken from the `dataset` object of a small number of HTML elements, and that step may take longer before the transaction is even opened.

However, I'd like to feel more confident that this is coded as close to "fail proof" as possible, and would like to know how to prevent these two transactions from ever blocking or interfering in any way causing the loss of data or program failure.

I don't really know what to provide for a code example because there is nothing to show but a textarea element with a `change` event and a set of radio buttons, also with a change event, that invokes a function to gather data and open a write transaction before hiding one tab and showing the other.

Everything works and has not failed once yet, but how can I code it to be certain?

Thank you.

**Addition** After agonizing over this for awhile, I think I misunderstood the concept of blocking in indexedDB.  I just assumed it had to do with two write transactions attempting to write to the same object store at the same time, but after reading further I don't think that is the case. If I understand correctly, this MDN [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction) states that transactions are processed in the order they appear in the code, and the example is of two write transactions.

Thus, for my question of a `change` event triggering a write transaction at the "same" time as another write transaction is triggered, it would appear the only concern would be that one transaction overwrites the data written by the other transaction. The browser will handle the rest and I don't have to worry about transactions interfering or blocking, apart from their order when important.  Blocking appears to be version change concern on an open database.

Regarding my original question, the `change` event always completed first in testing because its transaction was always opened first since it fires, I assume, on a `blur` event on the `textarea` which takes place before the `change` event on the radio buttons which fires on `mouseup` triggering the second write transaction.  I assume that the second write transaction opened on the same object store won't begin until the first completes; but there isn't that level of description in the referenced document apart from below.

> After the code is executed the object store should contain the value "2", since trans2 should run after trans1.

The point being that even if the first write transaction takes considerably longer relative to the second, the second will not start until after the first completes, and the only concern is the second transaction potentially overwriting data written in the first.

Sometimes I get myself confused and make issues where there aren't any and the coders of the browser have already taken care of it.

If I am still misunderstanding, I'd appreciate being corrected.  Thank you.